# Writing data into file

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm trying to make a txt log file with the actions that happens in my app. I want to save some text whenever the app is connecting to the server o displaying new info.

Well, how do I write to a file? I've tried using the method writeToFile: but it's not working because fileExistsAtPath: is returning NO.

My code is:

```
NSString *file_path = @"mylog.txt"; 
NSString *log = @"Hello World!!\n"; 
[log writeToFile:file_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
```

Thanks!

PS: Oh, would it be readable through Organizer with the iPhone plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the < App_Home >/Documents folder for storing Documents

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file_Path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.txt"];    
[log writeToFile:file_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
```

But normally if you want to see and dump things while running the app,
you could just use NSLog() which outputs it in the console.

Comment: I do use NSLog but there's lots of lines which are not from my app. Moreover, I want to see what has happened in my app during, for example, the hole day and I can't carry with me the laptop and have a look every 5 minutes, hehe. I'm gonna try with your code, thanks.

Comment: Okay Gotschi, it's working now! Is there any chance to append the text instead of rewriting the information? Thanks!

Comment: NSString's writeToFile cannot append. You can use an NSFileHandle created with fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: and then continuously write data to it using writeData:, though. There are also a few 3rd party iOS logging utilities floating around that might be easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method I wrote:

```
+(NSString*)createPath:(NSString*)fileName{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localizedPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]];

    //NSLog(@"%@",localizedPath);
    return localizedPath;
}
```

It will return you a path for your file. You only need to give it a name.